# How to Create a table in Sequelize to store in Postgressql with NodeJS

Tags: node.js, postgresql, express, sequelize.js, rdbms

Am a newbie to Postgres and Sequelize i have successfully connected to DB trying to create a table in DB that is where am struck am getting an error the tablename doesn't exist

```
sequelize.authenticate().then(() => {
  console.log("Success!");
  var News = sequelize.define('likes', {
    title: {
      type: Sequelize.STRING
    },
    content: {
      type: Sequelize.STRING
    }
    }, {
     freezeTableName: true
   });
   News.create({
     title: 'Getting Started with PostgreSQL and Sequelize',
     content: 'Hello there'
   });
   News.findAll({}).then((data) => {
     console.log(data);
   }).catch((err) => {
     console.log(err);
   });
}).catch((err) => {
  console.log(err);
});
```

Where am making a mistake? It says error: relation "likes" doesn't exist. Any kind of help is appreciated

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Sequelize only creates tables through `sync` or migrations. Your model, `News` has a `sync` method, that when called will do one of a few things

If called with no params, it will create the table if it doesn't exist

if called like this `News.sync({ force: true })` it will drop the current table if it exists and make a new one.

if called like this `News.sync({ alter: true })` it will add any new fields that are not in the model yet (this is a v4 feature).

These techniques can be useful when rapidly prototyping, but the best solution is to use migrations. Migrations allow you to keep track of changes to your database across development, different git branches, and production. Its by far the best solution, but does come with a small amount of upfront cost and buy-in.

If you're working on a hackathon style project, I'd just go with `{alter: true}`, but if you're building something you're going to be working on for a while, definitely get to know the [migrations API](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/migrations.html).

Comment: `News.sync({force: false}).then(function (err) {
    if(err) {
        console.log('An error occur while creating table');
    } else{
        console.log('Item table created successfully');
    }
});`

Comment: The above comment is the one am trying to do in console it prints An error occured while creating table however the table gets created and i can insert the values too. And by the way can you give me an simple example of that migrations API

Comment: It doesn't print out any error it consoles the table name "user"

Comment: Ah, I see. `.then` does not report errors. Param one of `.then` is the success result. to look for errors use `.catch`

Comment: Used catch no errors printed thanks for helping me out bro am newbie to sequelize want to explore more so can you suggest me the resources for the same

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46454303/error-while-performing-join-in-sequelize-nodejs-with-postgresql

Comment: can you answer that question ?